# Unknown process always does something with all USB drives

Tags: windows, windows-10, filesystems, usb-flash-drive, process

Every time I'm trying to format **any** of my **fully empty** USB stick I get this error.
[image]

Every time I'm clicking on the button "eject" to **any** of my **fully empty** USB stick in Windows Explorer I get this error.
[image]

I tried a lot of different things to fix this issue:

1. I closed all my software.
2. I restarted Windows Explorer in Task Manager.
3. I disabled Windows Defender(I don't have any exra antivirus).
4. I logged off from my Microsoft account and restarted the PC a lot of times.
5. I formated all my USB sticks in FAT32, NTFS, and exFAT formats.
6. I deleted all volumes of all my USB sticks and created them again.
7. I changed all the letters of all my USB drives.
8. I deleted the folder of mounted drives in Registry.
9. I researched all active processes in Resources Monitor. None does something with my empty USB drives. But all my empty USB drives almost always have Active Time 0.01%, I believe it must be 0.00%, so something does something with them.

Here's the screenshot from Resource Monitor.
[image]

Here're the screenshots from Process Explorer. There are 2 processes that do something with my fully empty USB drive(disk E). I believe they are the reason for those troubles.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Maybe someone knows how to fix this issue?

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe mode ?

Comment: It's still in use somewhere within the [Windows Shell](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_shell) - does killing _all_ `explorer.exe` instances, then starting `explorer.exe`, resolve the issue? _(`explorer.exe` is the Windows Shell - the first start of `explorer.exe` starts the Windows Shell, whereas every invocation after the first starts File Explorer)_. For example, I've always had issues with the Window Shell giving up Exclusive USB Drive Access for Rufus to format a drive _(I always have to use `Alt`+`,` to disable Exclusive USB Drive Locking)_

Comment: Can't imagine this isn't a duplicate ..

Answer (score 0):

To find the process that is using disk `X:` do the following :

- Download [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)
- Unpack and run `procexp.exe` as Administrator
- Click the magnifying-glass icon
- In the Search dialog, enter the search string of `X:` and click Search.

This will find all processes that have opened `X:`.

Now there are three cases :

- If the process is an installed product, modify its settings to ignore `X:`
- If the process belongs to System, then this is Windows. Check in
  *Start > indexing options* if perhaps Windows is indexing the drive.
  See this
  [article](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/remove-windows-indexing-service-usb-drives-64086.html)
  to remove `X:` from indexing.
  Another possibility is the antivirus real-time scanner.
- It's possible that Process Monitor will find nothing, and we're
  then back to square one.

Answer (score 0):

In case the suggested ProcessMonitor (Great Suggestion) does not, handle will, made by sysinternals as well.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle

Straight from the page..

**Ever wondered which program has a particular file or directory open? Now you can find out. Handle is a utility that displays
information about open handles for any process in the system. You can
use it to see the programs that have a file open, or to see the object
types and names of all the handles of a program.**

The easiest way is pipe it to a text file and search the resulting file for any files open on that device, that will show you the process that has the open handles to any file on the drive.

```
handle > handles.txt & notepad handles.txt
```

Note: Handles can be opened and closed fast, so if you do not find one, then either windows is in error someway and there are really no open handles, or you hit it in between, run it a few more times until you catch it.